# Verifying KKT conditions required for equivalence of primal and dual optimization (from Andrew Ng notes)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am studying [Andrew Ng's note](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf) on Support Vector Machines. On page 10 it showed the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions that  $w^∗, α^∗\text{ and } β^∗$ should satisfy when $d^{*} = p^{*}$.

[image]
Later on page 12, It is written we should be able to verify the KKT conditions are holding true as it is shown in the red box image shown below.

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone explain more how should I verify 6$^{th}$ KKT condition in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the paragraph at the bottom of page 9, which lays out what is known as the Slater condition for strong duality of a convex optimization problem.  You need to have a convex objective to be minimized, affine functions in any equality constraints, convex functions in any (<=) inequality constraints, and there needs to be at least one vector x that is strictly feasible (that is g_i(x) < b_i for each constraint) with respect to the inequality constraints and feasible with respect to the equality constraints.  If those conditions are satisfied then strong duality will hold.

The author is asking you to verify that the optimization problem stated at the start of section 6 satisfies these conditions.  Is the objective a convex function?  Are the g functions in the constraints (after rewriting them as <= inequalities) convex?  Is there a strictly feasible solution?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I still have a follow-up question, if you don't mind. Based on my understanding, to conclude $d^* = p^*$ we have 2 ways: the 3 conditions at the end of page 9 holding true or satisfying KKT condition(3-7). Conditions (3), (4), and (5) are holding true based on assumptions we made to obtain $w^*$. For the $6^{th}$ condition I tried to substitute $w^*$ and $b^*$ in $g_i$, to verify it is always $\leq0$. But I couldn't. That made me think,  am I supposed to do that or $6^{th}$ is holding true by initial assumption?I got confused here. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have a clear understanding of your question.  Condition (6) in the KKT conditions simply says that $w^{*}$ satisfies the inequality constraints.  If $w^{*}$ is an optimal solution to the optimization problem then it must be feasible with respect to these constraints. What supposedly optimal $w^{*}$ are you substituting into the constraints?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assumed optimal $w$ is  $w^* =\displaystyle \sum_i ^ m \alpha_i y^{(i)}x^{(i)}$, since it makes the derivate with respect to $w$ equal to zero. I am under the assumption that we need to substitue $w^*$ in KKT conditions, since it mentioned "you should be able to verify the conditions required for $p^*=d^*$ and KKT conditions (3-7) to hold ... .".

Comment: The author is saying that the conditions at the bottom of page 9 are satisfied (and asking you to confirm this.)  It is a theorem that if these conditions on page 9 are satisfied, then optimal primal and dual solutions will satisfy the KKT conditions.  Nothing in the material that you've quoted has told you how to find a primal-dual optimal solution.